# Writing to a JSON column type in BigQuery using Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql

I have a column of type JSON in my BigQuery schema definition. I want to write to this from a Java Spark Pipeline but I cannot seem to find a way that this is possible.

[image: schema definition with type]

If create a Struct of the JSON it results in a `RECORD` type.
And if I use `to_json` like below it turns converts into a `STRING` type.

`dataframe = dataframe.withColumn("JSON_COLUMN, functions.to_json(functions.col("JSON_COLUMN)))`

I know BigQuery has support for JSON columns but is there any way to write to them with Java Spark currently?

Comment: We are working on it and json support will be released soon

Comment: Hi @B-Brennan, I have posted the answer as Community wiki. So If my answer addressed your question, please consider upvoting and accepting it. If not, let me know so that the answer can be improved. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DavidRabinowitz mentioned in the comment, feature to insert JSON type data into BigQuery using `spark-bigquery-connector` will be released soon.

All the updates regarding the BigQuery features will be updated in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes).

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.

Comment: I dont see this feature released until now for spark bigquery connector.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment from @DavidRabinowitz this feature was not available until 2022 and based on our tests and BQ documentation it is not available yet.

I tried to create a table with JSON type column before publishing from Spark to BQ. After publishing the column type got changed to String.
For workaround we are using,

```
SELECT PARSE_JSON(jsonField) as json_data FROM `project.dataset.table`
```